# Expand and collapse rows through a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to expand and collapse the last 2 rows in a table via button?
When the page loads those rows has to be hidden.

here is the table:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
        <th style="background: #00A000; color: #fff;">Match Schedule</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr id="1">
        <td class="active">asd<br><p class="" style="color: red;">- Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</p1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="danger">asd<br><p class="" style="color: red;"> - Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="active">asd<br><p class="" style="color: red;"> - Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="danger">asd<br><p class="" style="color: red;"> - Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="active">asd<br><p class="" style="color: red;"> - Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="danger">asd<br><p class="" style="color: red;"> - Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your current markup, you can

1. Select the last two elements using
   `tbody tr:nth-last-child(-n+2)` and then
2. Use `toggleClass` to switch between the classes defined to hide and show it.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('tbody tr:nth-last-child(-n+2)').toggleClass("display");
});
```

```css
tbody tr:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  display: none;
}

.display {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="background: #00A000; color: #fff;">Match Schedule</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td class="active">asd
        <br>
        <p class="" style="color: red;">- Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="danger">asd
        <br>
        <p class="" style="color: red;">- Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">asd
        <br>
        <p class="" style="color: red;">- Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="danger">asd
        <br>
        <p class="" style="color: red;">- Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">asd
        <br>
        <p class="" style="color: red;">- Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="danger">asd
        <br>
        <p class="" style="color: red;">- Start 15 Aug 2015 21:00</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>

<button>Press me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap's collapse function in order to wrap the last two rows in a div and control is via a button.

More information: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse